# Firebase cloud function: execution finish time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an image resize cloud function. When I look back at the logs, I see function execution took 1014 ms. But after the execution, the function still show logs (is doing what it supposed to do, the image gets resized).

[image: Cloud function progress]

So is there a delay on the logs or does it really take more than a minute to execute that function (what would be a problem for the bill?)?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: this is my code:

```js
export const makeRoundPicture = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  console.log(context.auth.uid);

  if (context.auth.uid != null) {
    await tmp.dir(async function _tempDirCreated(err: any, path: any) {
      if (err) throw err;

      var initialurl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproject.appspot.com/o/"+context.auth.uid+".jpg?alt=media";

      const options = {
        url: initialurl,
        dest: path
      }

      console.log('Dir: ', path);

      await download.image(options)
        .then(async (filename: any) => {
          console.log('Saved');
          console.log(filename['filename']);

          var uploadPath = filename['filename'];

          var original = uploadPath; 
          var output = path+"photo.png";
          var size = 230;

          await gm(original)
            .resize(size, size)
            .write(output, function() {
              gm(size, size, 'none')
                .fill(output)
                .drawCircle(size/2.05 ,size/2.05, size/2.05, 0)
                .write(output, async function(err6: any) {
                  console.log(err6 || 'done');
                  await bucket.upload(output, {
                    destination: "myfolder/"+context.auth.uid+".png",
                  });
                });
            });
        })
        .catch((err4: any) => console.error(err4))
    });
  } else {
    console.log("unAuthorized request");
  }
});
```

Comment: Without seeing the code, there's not much we can say.  It's very possible that you're doing something wrong.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A first guess is that you have an operation that continues after the final `}` of the Cloud Function is evaluated. My first concern there would not be about the billing impact, but whether the function is guaranteed to work. Please post the minimal, complete/standalone code with which you can reproduce this behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added all the code of the cloud function, thanks!

Comment: The indentation of this code is not consistent, making it difficult to read.  Could you clean it up?  Also it doesn't look syntactically correct.  Are you really passing a function declaration to `tmp.dir()`?

Comment: I'll try to clean it up, I write in typescript, no errors, the function seems to work... UPDATE: cleaned it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from mixing Promises and callback APIs.

The `async`/`await` syntax only works when chaining promises together.

As an example, this `await tmp.dir` line does not wait for `_tempDirCreated` to evaluate and return it's awaited promises.

```js
await tmp.dir(async function _tempDirCreated(err: any, path: any) {
  /* ... */
});
// this line gets called immediately
```

So in short, you will need to either adopt promise-based APIs, such as `tmp-promise` in place `node-tmp`, or wrap your entire function in a Promise.

```js
const tmp = require('tmp-promise');

export const makeRoundPicture = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called while authenticated.');
  }

  console.log('Called by: ', context.auth.uid);

  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  const { path: tmpDirPath } = await tmp.dir();

  const initialurl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproject.appspot.com/o/"+context.auth.uid+".jpg?alt=media";

  const options = {
    url: initialurl,
    dest: tmpDirPath
  }

  console.log('Temp Dir: ', tmpDirPath);

  let { filename: originalFilename } = await download.image(options);

  console.log('Saved: ', originalFilename);

  let output = tmpDirPath + "photo.png";
  let size = 230;

  await gmMakeRoundPicture(originalFilename, output, size);

  await bucket.upload(output, {
    destination: "myfolder/"+context.auth.uid+".png",
  });
});

function gmMakeRoundPicture(inFilePath, outFilePath, size) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gm(inFilePath)
      .resize(size, size)
      .write(outFilePath, async (err) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);

        gm(size, size, 'none')
          .fill(outFilePath)
          .drawCircle(size/2.05, size/2.05, size/2.05, 0)
          .write(outFilePath, (err) => err ? reject(err) : resolve());
      })
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort! Amazing! I'm writing in typeScript: I get this error for the functon: gmMakeRoundPicture. Expression has type `void`. Put it on its own line as a statement.

Comment: I think you need to change `function gm...size) {` to `function gm...size): Promise {` or similar.

Comment: Thanks, I now commented this line :  if (err) return reject(err); and that also lets me update the function, I'm now testing it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah right. Typescript will complain about that but don't just comment it out as it's important. Instead change it to `if (err) { reject(err); return; }`.

Comment: Thanks! It's uploading with that code, because if I comment it, it gives this error in the console: TypeError: gm().write() expects a callback function.

Comment: Still getting this error, even when I added the new line: TypeError: gm().write() expects a callback function

Comment: Yup. Just caught that myself, check the edit it above where I forgot to add in an `(err) =>`. But because of Typescript again, you might have to change it to `(err) => { err ? reject(err) : resolve() }`

Comment: Thanks! I'm now trying it with this code : return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      gm(inFilePath)
        .resize(size, size)
        .write(outFilePath, async (err: any) => {
          if (err) { reject(err); return; }
  
          gm(size, size, 'none')
            .fill(outFilePath)
            .drawCircle(size/2.05, size/2.05, size/2.05, 0)
            .write(outFilePath, (err2: any) => err ? reject(err2) : resolve());
        })
    });

Comment: It works perfectly! (and so fast!) I'm very grateful for your time and effort you put into this! I've been struggeling for days with this function & now it finally works perfect! Thank you so much man! Have great holidays! Thanks Thanks Thanks!

Comment: One last tidbit, you renamed the second `err` to `err2` but missed one rename: `(err2: any) => { err2 ? reject(err2) : resolve() }`